¿Cómo hacer un subset de un DF en el que el condicional sea que los elementos de dos variables coincidan con la combinación de éstas en otro DF?
Tengo un DF con las variables categóricas "x" e "y", además de muchas otras variables.
Tengo otro DF con diferentes combinaciones de los elementos de las variables "x" e "y" que son de mi interés.
¿Cómo puedo hacer un subset del primer DF en el que solo aparezcan las observaciones con las combinaciones de "x" e "y" que están incluidas en el segundo DF?

Indica por medio de etiquetas el lenguaje en el que estás trabajando, pues la respuesta no es la misma en distintos lenguajes. Por otro lado, vendría bien que publiques algo de código, un [mcve], de dónde pueda partir quien se tome el tiempo de escribir una respuesta.
